# Contagem de lista sem repetir print - Python

Tags: python, lista

to resolvendo uma lista da faculdade mas não encontro uma maneira de mostrar a contagem dos números sem que repita a print. Por ex, quando o número for repetido eu quero que print apenas uma vez e não tô sabendo fazer, pois o for que varre a lista faz com que apareça repetidamente a contagem. Segue o código

```py
numero = int(input("Número: "))
freio = 0
l = []

while numero != freio:
    l.append(numero)
    numero = int(input("Número: "))

for x in l:
    if l.count() == 1:
         print("O Número ", x, "aparece", l.count(x), "vez.")
    else:
         print("O Número ", x, "aparece", l.count(x), "vezes.")
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico agradecido.

Comment: Dei downvote pq acredito que sua pergunta está fora do escopo do site (é um exemplo desse caso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5486#5486 ). Como sempre, estou disposto a reavaliar meu voto diante de um reformulação. Abs,

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar do Counter das coleções do Python, que vai contar os elementos pra você:

```
from collections import Counter

numero = int(input("Número: "))
freio = 0
l = []

while numero != freio:
  l.append(numero)
  numero = int(input("Número: "))

#Transforma sua lista já efetuando a contagem dos itens repetidos
counter = Counter(l)

for x in counter:
  if counter[x] == 1:
    print("O Número", x, "aparece", counter[x], "vez.")
  else:
    print("O Número", x, "aparece", counter[x], "vezes.")
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/GrownBlushingIntegrationtesting

---

Também é possível transformar sua lista em um dicionário, sendo o número a chave do dicionário e o valor a contagem:

```
numero = int(input("Número: "))
freio = 0
l = []

while numero != freio:
  l.append(numero)
  numero = int(input("Número: "))

#Cria um dicionário com base na lista
d = {x:l.count(x) for x in l}

for x in d:
  if d[x] == 1:
    print("O Número", x, "aparece", d[x], "vez.")
  else:
    print("O Número", x, "aparece", d[x], "vezes.")
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/ImaginativeLightpinkScan